# Creating efficiently a dictionary in pyspark using list derived from df columns

Tags: list, apache-spark, pyspark, user-defined-functions, azure-synapse

I created this function in python using pandas dataframe, and I'd like to use it also in spark.

What I'm doing with this function is :

- converting the df column to a list ( t1 )
- converting the unique values of the column to a list ( t2 )
- creating a list for each unique value of each feature ( t ). this list takes value 1 when the unique value is present in t1, 0 otherwise.
  at the end the result is a dictionary with the unique values of each feature as key and as argument a list with value 1 when the key (the unique value) appears and 0 otherwise.

feat_list is just a list with all the column names.

```
  def binary_dict(pandas_df, feat_list):
    
    dict_feature = dict()
    
    for col in feat_list:
    
    t1 = pandas_df[col].tolist()
    t2 = pandas_df[col].unique().tolist()

    for value in t2:
    
        t = []
    
        for i in range (0, len(t1)):
        
            if value == t1[i]:
            
                t.append(1)
            
            else:
            
                t.append(0)
            
        cc = str(col)
        vv = "_" + str(value)
        cv = cc + vv

        dict_feature[cv] = t
        
return dict_feature
```

I tried using

```
t1 = df.select("col_name").rdd.flatMap(list).collect()
```

for creating t1 but it took over 20 minutes to create the list for a single column. I got something like 100 columns. Is there a way to convert this function to spark efficiently?

Thanks everyone for the answers!

PS: I'm using synapse analytics by azure/microsoft, Python 3.8 and pyspark 3.1.

Comment: If I understand the question correct, the result would be an array type column and all arrays have as many elements as the original dataframe has rows?

Comment: yep, you got that!

Comment: In this case you have to collect all the data of the whole Spark dataframe on a single executor to be able to construct that array. This means that a Spark solution has no advantages over your existing Pandas code as the computation cannot run in parallel on several machines.

Comment: Thanks for the advice! I tought I had to collect but I was looking for another way, but it seems I have no choice. Thanks!